# Python slumber, cannot get key values from .items()

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary

```
[{'start_date': None, 'end_date': None, 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76564', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': True, 'name': 'Backlog', 'hidden': False, 'iteration_type': 0, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 211, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76564}, {'start_date': None, 'end_date': None, 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76565', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Archive', 'hidden': False, 'iteration_type': 2, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 2, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76565}, {'start_date': '2016-02-01', 'end_date': '2016-02-13', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76693', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Godzilla', 'hidden': False, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 27, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76693}, {'start_date': '2016-01-18', 'end_date': '2016-01-30', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76694', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Frodo', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 26, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76694}, {'start_date': '2016-01-04', 'end_date': '2016-01-16', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76695', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Ewok', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 35, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76695}, {'start_date': '2015-12-21', 'end_date': '2016-01-02', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76696', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Dexter Jettster', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 3, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76696}, {'start_date': '2015-12-07', 'end_date': '2015-12-19', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76697', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Chewbacca', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 26, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76697}, {'start_date': '2015-11-23', 'end_date': '2015-12-05', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76698', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Boss Nass', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 27, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76698}, {'start_date': '2015-11-09', 'end_date': '2015-11-21', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76699', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Ackbar', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 31, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76699}, {'start_date': '2015-10-26', 'end_date': '2015-11-07', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76700', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Han Solo', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 25, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76700}, {'start_date': '2015-10-12', 'end_date': '2015-10-24', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76701', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Harry Potter', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 33, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76701}, {'start_date': '2015-09-28', 'end_date': '2015-10-10', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76702', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Boba Fett', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 36, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76702}, {'start_date': '2015-09-14', 'end_date': '2015-09-26', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76703', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Darth Vader', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 15, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76703}, {'start_date': '2015-08-31', 'end_date': '2015-09-12', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76704', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Hellboy', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 15, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76704}, {'start_date': '2015-08-24', 'end_date': '2015-08-29', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76705', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'Old Man Sprint', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 3, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76705}, {'start_date': '2015-08-10', 'end_date': '2015-08-22', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/76706', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'PO System Sprint 3', 'hidden': True, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 14, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 76706}, {'start_date': '2016-02-15', 'end_date': '2016-02-27', 'url': '/projects/development16/iteration/78153', 'locked': False, 'default_iteration': False, 'name': 'H', 'hidden': False, 'iteration_type': 1, 'detail': '', 'story_count': 0, 'include_in_velocity': True, 'id': 78153}]
```

Above is variable iter_list from a Slumber API call.

I'm trying to gather keys out of the above information in Python 3.5.

```
for key, value in iter_list.items():
     print(key)
```

It's telling me that there is no items() attribute for iter_list.

The end goal is to provide the key names in a seperate dict or config file to pull from for use in search functions, instead of having to manually go look and what keys are in each API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iter_list` seems to be a list with a dictionary as its first element. Just access the first element and you'll get the dictionary:

```
for key, value in iter_list[0].items():
    print(key)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not accessing the right information. That actually works now and pulls the entire list. But it doesn't just give me the name of the item but instead both the item and the value associated with it.

so intead of 'locked':False I just want the names of each one, the contents "false" I don't need.

I think I'm asking the wrong question in the original statement?

Comment: nevermind I had my syntax wrong. You are correct by using the first element and pulling the dict it does give the key and not both.

Answer (score 1):

You want to access the items in the dictionary that's the first (and only) element in the list.

```
for key, value in iter_list[0].items():
     print(key)
```